# Neural Network Prediction Intervals in R

Tags: r, neural-network, tableau-api, prediction

I am trying to compute prediction intervals for my neural network created with the [neuralnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/) package.

I use R in Tableau Software, by creating .RData files containing my functions and loaded in Tableau.

It's a simple NN, with one hidden layer containing 5 nodes. I searched and found this package : [nnetpredint](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnetpredint/)

So I tried to use it, using their examples.
I tried also to change the way I use it (train/test in same data frame, separated data frames with the same columns names etc.)

And the best result I had was the prediction, but without the `lowerBound` and `upperBound` columns.
In fact, I got exactly the same result as when I use `compute(myNN, etc.)`, but I don't have the second and third columns.

Thanks for your help,

***EDIT :***
My data is coming from tableau, my function take five parameters which are :
ValuesToExplain,train1,train2,test1,test2. 
Then, i create and train my NN with the 3first and try to compute the two last.
(test1 = k*train1 and test2 = k2*train2 for now but it will probably move in the future).

Here is my whole code :

```
NNetwork <- function(objectiveValues, knownValues1, knownValues2, newData, newData2){

  numberOfColumn = 3

  ##Create the training dataframe
  training <- data.frame(objectiveValues, knownValues1,knownValues2)
  training[which(is.na(training[,"objectiveValues"])),"objectiveValues"]<- mean(training[,"objectiveValues"], na.rm = TRUE)
  training[which(is.na(training[,"knownValues1"])),"knownValues1"]<- mean(training[,"knownValues1"], na.rm = TRUE)
  training[which(is.na(training[,"knownValues2"])),"knownValues2"]<- mean(training[,"knownValues2"], na.rm = TRUE)


  ## Create the testing dataframe

  testing <- data.frame(objectiveValues,newData,newData2)
  names(testing) <- c("objectiveValues", "knownValues1", "knownValues2")
  testing[which(is.na(testing[,"objectiveValues"])),"objectiveValues"]<- mean(testing[,"objectiveValues"], na.rm = TRUE)
  testing[which(is.na(testing[,"knownValues1"])),"knownValues1"]<- mean(testing[,"knownValues1"], na.rm = TRUE)
  testing[which(is.na(testing[,"knownValues2"])),"knownValues2"]<- mean(testing[,"knownValues2"], na.rm = TRUE)



  ## Scaling

  maxs <- apply(training, 2, max) 
  mins <- apply(training, 2, min)
  trainingScaled <- as.data.frame(scale(training, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins))



  testingScaled <- as.data.frame(scale(testing, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins))


  ### NeuralNetwork Part 

  library(neuralnet)
  n <- names(trainingScaled)

  f <- as.formula(paste("objectiveValues ~", paste(n[!n %in% "objectiveValues"], collapse = " + ")))


  # Training NN
  nn <- neuralnet(f, data=trainingScaled,hidden=5,linear.output=TRUE)


  # Using NN
  computedTrainingScaled <- compute(nn,trainingScaled[,2:numberOfColumn])
  computedFromNNScaled <- compute(nn,testingScaled[,2:numberOfColumn])


  # UnScaling 
  computedTraining <- computedTrainingScaled$net.result*(max(training$objectiveValues)-min(training$objectiveValues))+min(training$objectiveValues)
  computedFromNN <- computedFromNNScaled$net.result*(max(training$objectiveValues)-min(training$objectiveValues))+min(training$objectiveValues)


  RSquare = (1-( (sum((training$objectiveValues - computedTraining)^2))/(sum((training$objectiveValues - mean(training$objectiveValues))^2)) ))*100
  RSE = sum((training$objectiveValues - computedTraining)^2)/nrow(training)
  res <- (1:nrow(training))

  library(nnetpredint) # Getting prediction confidence interval
  x <- trainingScaled[,2:numberOfColumn]
  y <- trainingScaled[1]
  newData <- testingScaled[,2:numberOfColumn]
  # S3 generic method: Object of nn
  yPredInt <- nnetPredInt(nn, x, y, newData)


  for(i in 1:nrow(training)){
    res[i] <- paste(computedFromNN[i],RSquare,RSE, sep="#")
  }

  return(res)

}

save(NNetwork, file = "NNetwork.RData")
```

Here, i removed the part using the nnetpredint pckage because it was not working, but it was like this :

```
  library(nnetpredint) 
  y <- trainingScaled
  x <- trainingScaled[,2:3]
  newData <- testingScaled[,2:3]

  yPredInt <- nnetPredInt(nn, x, y, newData)
```

My problem is that when I try to access yPredInt$lowerBound or yPredInt$upperBound , they don't exist.

Comment: You need to provide more details to make this issue reproducible. What code and data did you use? Show the output you got and your desired output.

Comment: epo3 - I edited my post, thank you.

Comment: @VinhasK, Had you any success in computing prediction intervals? I am facing same issue.

Comment: No, sorry. I'm still trying to find a solution. In case of success, I d post here my solution.